# Make s4-titlerow always visible

Tags: 2013, master-page, ribbon

Would it be possible to make the s4-titlerow always visible?
By always visible I mean, even when the ribbon is active.

i tried changing the position of the titlerow with css position, but it only changes when the ribbon is closed. When it is active it always disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do by placing below CSS:

```
#s4-titlerow { display:block !important; }
```

`#s4-titlerow` is the default SharePoint class for showing the title row. When you open the ribbon it will make this `div` as hidden.

As other approach you can go with your custom master page.

Here is the custom starter masterpage available that you can use: [Starter Master page CodePlex](https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Pradip's answer is very good but by this way you will always see s4-titlerow, in pop-up dialogs also.

In my case it is not good to see s4-titlerow in dialog.

My solution is - create new master page and change s4-titlerow id to something(for example s4-titlerow-custom) and change name of class s4-titlerowhidetitle to something(for example s4-titlerowhidetitle-custom ). It will work without CSS changes.